# Select number of distinct value below date for all date into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `trackers` and I would like to count the number of value that appears in the table below the date for each date into the table.
So my request in the following :

```
SELECT distinct(DATE(`server_time`)) FROM `trackers` WHERE `event`=37
```

Then for each date return by the request I do :

```
SELECT count(distinct `label` ) FROM `trackers` WHERE `event`=37 AND DATE(`server_time`)<=mydate
```

This works but is there a way to have only 1 request which return distinct(DATE(`server_time`)) with the number count(distinct `label` )?

For now if I have 3 dates then I need to do 4 requests. I would like to have only one.
I have years of data and doing multiple request on the MySQL table is not time efficient...

Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: order them by date and limit the return rows to 1, SELECT count(distinct `label` ) FROM `track__trackers` WHERE `event`=37 AND DATE(`server_time`)<=mydate ORDER by server_time ASC LIMIT 1